# What layer of the OS/drivers/X/Wayland might cause touchpad problems in both synaptic and libinput?

Tags: touchpad, synaptic, libinput

I am wondering, what layer of the stack might be causing issues in my touchpad if both the synaptic driver and the libinput driver show the same issue?

I would be using my trackpad and intermittently it will just stop reporting motion events and occasionally it would miss clicks too. I need to remove my finger from the trackpad and put it back down, and then motion events are reported again. It happens multiple times a minute.

`libinput debug-events` shows that events simply stop being generated while I am moving my finger (until I lift my finger and start touching the trackpad again). Same with `xev`. Happens on both the `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` and `xserver-xorg-input-libinput` drivers.

I am running Debian on a 2012 MacBook Pro. Switching from Debian testing to Debian unstable is when the problem started (no complaints about it, I know "unstable" means "unstable").

When I boot to a Mac OSX partition, the trackpad works find under that os.

Could it be a grossly miscalibrated palm-rejection under Debian unstable? The problem happens even if I very carefully use a single finger extended away from my palm to touch the trackpad.